# Session value is passed using curl to another project and the value is received in "{"abc@gmail_com":null}" this format

Tags: php, laravel, session, curl

Using curl for the first time in my project. I have used session in my project. When I do `{{ dd(session()->all()) }}` I get the desired result
as  `"email" => "abc@gmail.com"`

But when I'm passing this variable through curl to my other project, there the value is received in this format `"{"abc@gmail_com":null}"`

THE .com IS CHANGED TO _com and there is a null

Therefore I am unable to fetch record from database against that email address. Following is my code:

```
        $sendData = Session::get('email');
//        dd($sendData);
        $url = 'http://localhost/myproject/project-apis/public/index.php/myRequest';

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$sendData);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);
    //        dd($server_output);
            $dataReceive = json_decode($server_output);
            if($dataReceive->status == 'TRUE'){
                $profile = $dataReceive->profile;
            }
            else{
                $profile = array();
            }
```

Please help me out.

Note: I am not using artisan serve in this project so my url is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is expecting either an array or a urlencoded string:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

But this line is only storing the email address in `$sendData`:

```
$sendData = Session::get('email');
```

Try setting `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` like this instead:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['email' => $sendData]);
```